# Show $\#\{(A,B) \vert A \subseteq B \subseteq [n]\} = 3^n $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to show that:
$$
\#\{(A,B) \vert A \subseteq B \subseteq [n]\} = 3^n$$ for $n \geq 1$. 
That is, how can I show that there are $3^n$ pairs of subsets $(A,B)$ of a set with $n$ elements such that the former set $A$ is contained in the latter set $B$.

Comment: This question is not really very clear.  What do you mean by $[n]$?  And how can a set equal a number?

Comment: @GregoryGrant one could spell this out but it is a relatively common notation for a set with $n$ elements. (I have to admit I misunderstood your second sentence though.)

Comment: I see, the # symbol was missing when I asked that question.  I have a phd in math but have never seen $[n]$ used for a set with $n$ elements.  What is a generic set with $n$ elements anyway?  I still don't understand what $A\subseteq B\subseteq [n]$ means.

Comment: [n] is {1 $\dots$ n}

Comment: @GregoryGrant normally it is not a generic set but $\{0, 1, \dots,  n-1\}$  or as Noah said $\{1,  \dots , n\}$.  But it does not really matter. You could also say let $[n]$ be whatever fixed set with $n$ elements. And then you study the question. Just like you could consider the question how many subset a set with $n$ elements has and get $2^n$. OTOH I am really not sure what is unclear about $A \subset B \subset [n]$. You choose  a subset $B$ of $[n]$ and choose a subset of that subset. How many ways are there to do this.

Comment: i try to show this with this idea: i choose one element (a $\in [n]$ then for all a can $a \in A and B$ or $a \notin A , \in B$ or $a \notin A , \notin B$ then i have n ways to do this. is this the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can describe a pair $(A,B)$ uniquely by specifying for each $i\in [n]$ if this $i$ is in $0,1,2$ of the sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: its mean there are three ways to construct the pair (A,B) $i\in A, i\in B$ or $i\notin A, i\in B$ or $i\notin A, i\notin B$ is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, for each $i$ you have these $3$ choices. THis $n$ times. So $3^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The sets $B$ contained in $[n]$ can be partitioned by size: let's call each size $k$, with $0\le k\le n$. For a given $k$ the number of such sets $B$ is ${n\choose k}$. The number of sets $A$ contained in a given $B$ is $2^k$, which is independent of the particular set $B$. We can add all these, and get

$$\#\{(A,B) \vert A \subseteq B \subseteq [n]\} = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}2^k$$

By the binomial theorem, the sum can be rewritten as

$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}2^k1^{n-k}=(2+1)^k=3^k$$